# How to install a development Framework in MacOS for commandline build

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, continuous-integration, circleci

I have an iOS application that needs to be integrated into CI/CD pipeline in CircleCI. Most of my dependencies have been added using CocoPods. There is one particular dependency of OpenCV2 that is manually compiled and used. On the local development machine, It is simple to use with drag & drop in Xcode. But, while running the build on a CI server. We don't have access to GUI and need to link dependency from the command line. I have not found much of the resources dealing with this issue.

I have tried few options from this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/InstallingFrameworks.html

The framework that I am trying to use is compiled and zipped in an archive (opencv2.framework.zip and uploaded on Amazon S3. It is because the compiled framework is about 300 MB in size. So, I can't push it to the source repository. So, I download it using curl and unzip on CI machine. I have tried unzipping it to

- /System/Library/Frameworks
- /Library/Frameworks
- ~/Library/Frameworks

  gym --scheme "project" --workspace "project.xcworkspace"

None of them really worked.I would like a way to register this framework in the system so that linker can find it while linking.

1. Suggest a way to extract framework into a location which linker can automatically look into.
2. Suggest a way where I can link framework manually from command line build

Comment: are you using swift ?

Comment: yes, swift 3 and Objective C++

Answer (score -1):

I have never used OpenCV but a quick pod search gives this result, so looks like they are already supporting cocoapods.....

```
pod search opencv
-> OpenCV2 (3.2.0)
   OpenCV (Computer Vision) for iOS.
   pod 'OpenCV2', '~> 3.2.0'
   - Homepage: http://opencv.org
   - Source:   http://github.com/bcomeau/opencv/releases/download/3.2.0/opencv-3.2.0-ios-framework.zip
   - Versions: 3.2.0 [master repo]
```

Second:

You can use `Carthage` https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage

You can use both Cocoapods and Carthage at the same time as long as they are not downloading the same dependencies.

Create a private repo, follow the carthage tutorial for uploading frameworks https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#supporting-carthage-for-your-framework

then put opencv2 to your repo.

Then add your repo to your `cartfile`

Then before or after you install cocoapods, install carthage frameworks too.

It is a bit work but can solve your problem.

Third:
Looks like they also support Carthage 
https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source/issues/32

Look at the last couple of comments..